is there any way to fix the sound in ubuntu 22.04 huawei matebook d15 amd ryzen 5000 series?
I've downloaded Ubuntu 22.04 on my Huawei Matebook D15 with amd Ryzen 5000 series CPU but I don't have any sound. In the settings, I have only dummy output. Headphones doesn't work either. I've tried different solutions from the internet but nothing works.
aplay -l output:
03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller  
03:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 01)`

Is there any way to fix the issue?

The headphone and speaker channels are mixed up in the sound card driver for Linux distributions.
When headphones are connected, the system considers that sound should be output from the speakers. When the headphones are off, the system tries to output sound through them.
running this script should fix the sound

unfortunately it didn't help. there's "inxi -F" output for audio
Audio:
Device-1: AMD Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
Device-2: AMD Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor
driver: snd_rn_pci_acp3x
Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k6.5.0-28-generic running: yes
